# 2nd Internal HD not detected after re-install

Tags: windows-7

Previously I installed Windows 7 Home and then upgraded to Pro.  I performed a fresh install of Windows 7 Pro due to file corruption.

Windows 7 Pro didn't install on the original C: Drive, it installed itself on the other internal HD. Now the OS calls this the C: Drive and the original HD isn't detected.

I've considered swapping the cables between the two hard drives. If I do that, can I configure everything in BIOS alone, or would I need to configure the pins on the hard drives? ( I haven't done that before so I'd need a clear walk-through.)

Is there any other way to get the computer/OS to detect and access the HD that had been the C: Drive?

Comment: You only need to swap the pins if the hard drives are IDE. Sata drives are point to point, so there is no need. Google images of IDE and SATA if you aren't sure the difference.

Comment: Have you simply tried to switch the boot order of the devices?

Comment: I can't switch the boot order of the HDs because the original Drive isn't detected now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons that your other hard drive is not recognized.

- Missing Chipset drivers
- Hardware failure
- It is an IDE drive, and it is in the incorrect state (master / slave)
- It is turned off in the bios
- Corrupted MBR / Partition Table

**Steps to troubleshoot**

1. See if the drive shows up in [disk management](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm)
2. Determine if the hard drives are Sata or IDE
3. Go into the bios, and see if the drives are recognized, you may have disabled one by accident

If you have verified all this, and the drive still isn't recognized, try plugging it into a different computer. If the hard drive works on another computer, try the following:

1. Download the latest chipset drivers from your motherboard manufacture's website.
2. Try switching the mode from AHCI to IDE in the bios.

If all else fails, take the computer to a repair shop.